# Debug mode flag always running

Tags: c, linux, arguments

So I have a program that I made, but I am supposed to get debug mode to work only when the '-d' flag is given. For some reason, it is always running, even when -d is not given. I declare my debugMode to be FALSE in my program unless -d was given, but somewhere the logic is messed up and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Everywhere where I have, "If ( debugMode == TRUE ), it's running those statements.

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int debugMode = FALSE;


int main(int argc, char**argv){
    int i = 0; // loop counter
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if ('-' == argv[i][0] && 'd' == argv[i][1]){
            debugMode == TRUE;
            printf ("\n");
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the name of your program?

Comment: It if is `-daprogram` it will work just fine... (hint: `for (i = <?what?>`

Comment: Note that the comparison `debugMode == TRUE;` doesn't do anything useful.  I don't think that's sufficiently close to your actual code.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right. I forgot to set it. Although it's still evaluating to true which is weird.

Comment: `argv[0]` is always the program name. So to check the 1st argument -- you will want to start looking at `argv[1]`. Currently, the only thing that happens if `argv[1]` contains `-d` is you set a flag and `printf ("\n");` (which should be `putchar ('\n');` since you don't need `printf` to output a single character...)

Comment: As it stands, you have a comparison where you intend an assignment.  The code shown doesn't reproduce the problem, so we can't help you debug your problem.  Please consider deleting the question until you can create an MCVE ([MCVE]) that demonstrates the actual problem, then resuscitating it after you've edited it.  Or simply delete it.

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the problem, make sure you include stdio.h

Answer (score 0):

here you have issue in assignment .

```
 debugMode == TRUE;
```

above statement does not assign TRUE to debugMode and doesn't do any useful thing! you probably have simple copy+paste issue here ! use :

```
  debugMode = TRUE;
```